# Is there any open source projects on ros2?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native languafe. I hope that this question is not too much to ask, but is there any open source projects on ROS2, preferebly Foxy, that anyone could check. I'm relative new to ROS and especially ROS2 and I would be very grateful for links on such projects. I have problems with understanding controllers and how they work and I'm reading tutorials about them now but real working example would be an invaluable help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407796/is-there-any-open-source-projects-on-ros2?/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also use the stuff from irobot create 3
https://iroboteducation.github.io/create3_docs/

They also have gazebo simulation

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2022-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0